# How do I associate .htm's Edit option with Notepad in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a number of files on my Windows 7 machine with .htm extensions. When I right click on these files I get a menu of options (Open/Edit/Print etc.) The EDIT option is currently mapped to Microsoft Word and I want to map it to Notepad.

I have tried right clicking on the file and selecting Open With/Choose default program but that only lets me set the program for the Open menu item not the Edit menu item. I have also tried Start/Default Programs/Associate a file type, but this also only lets me change the Open option.

Any ideas? I am sure I used to be able to do this in Windows XP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To change it without using 3rd party software:

Open Internet Explorer. 
Go to Tools > Internet Options.
Select the Programs tab. 
Change the 'HTML Editing' option to whatever you want to use (e.g. Notepad).

Comment: Talk about hiding the setting away where you won't find it. I would never have thought to look there in a million years.

Comment: Apparently it works only with MS programs (Word, Notepad, Excel !?)

Comment: By using this method, the only way to use a custom program (other than ms) is to go into HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Default HTML Editor\shell\edit\command and change the value for your favorite editor path

Comment: I just used this to change the option (Word kept trying to open in Safe mode and failing anyway) and was pleasantly surprised to see TextPad in the available options.

Comment: Another registry key that needs to change to use a custom program is: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Shared\HTML\Default Editor\shell\edit\command. This is the key windows explorer reads to open a html file with 'Edit'.

Answer (score 6):

Reccommending **[Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com)** for this, because along with many other features, it was designed for Vista/Windows 7 and plays nice with UAC.

The context menu editor is quite powerful, allowing you to add or edit context menu items without hassle:

[image: Context Menu Editor]

Additionally, it allows you to *remove* that 'default programs' association that Windows won't let you un-check:

[image: Uncheck default programs]

Comment: I second this one. I like how it integrates with the control panel, as well.

Comment: I like it when people hack registry hacking. ;) +1 for the screenshots. @Factor Mystic

Answer (score 4):

I've used [FileTypesMan](http://nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) on several occasions and it has performed as expected (opening in its own window but performing the same task)

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is not file association, unless you want to associate Notepad as the default program to **open** all HTML files (rather than your web browser).

i recommend this method instead:

`1.` Enter the program's executable name (notepad.exe) as a subkey of these two registry key's shown below:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.htm\OpenWithList\notepad.exe]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html\OpenWithList\notepad.exe]
```

`2.` And add an "edit" subkey here:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe\shell\edit]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe\shell\edit\command]
Default = C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe "%1"
```

`3.` To change the default editor, replace the "Default" entry in this registry key
with the command line for your prefered editor:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Default HTML Editor]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Default HTML Editor\shell]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Default HTML Editor\shell\edit]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Default HTML Editor\shell\edit\command]
Default = C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe "%1"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Creative Element Power Tools](http://www.creativelement.com/powertools/) includes a File Type Doctor program that can do it...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Save this in a batch file `Add Edit Command To HTM.bat` & run:

```
reg add "HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\.htm\shell\Edit\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "notepad.exe \"%%1\"" /f
pause
```

This adds an Edit command to the `.htm` file context menu to be open with Notepad.

If you don't have Notepad in `PATH`, then put full path to Notepad instead of `notepad.exe`

The `SystemFileAssociations` is the location where you specify for example the `.htm` file type association for context menu and in the `shell` you put the `Edit command`.